# How to confirm Evernote Webhook Url is registered?

Tags: webhooks, evernote

As for document i have registered webhook endpoint and got email from support team as "Endpoint updated successfully".So I have tried to get notify when Evernote gets create or update but unfortunately I am not able to get any notification.My doubts are
-> Webhook endpoint is registered successfully or not?

->If registered successfully how to get notification url(like **[base URL]/?userId=[user ID]&notebookGuid=[notebook GUID]&reason=notebook_create**) format when account gets create or update?

Code I tried:
    //Just routing to function when notifys

```
function evernote_notification(response,request){
     var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url, true); 
     var queryAsObject = parsedUrl.query;
     console.log("evernote_notification:- queryAsObject- "+JSON.stringify(queryAsObject));
     var userId=parseUrl.query.userId;
     var guid=parseUrl.query.guid;
     var reagon=parseUrl.query.reason;
     console.log("evernote_notification:- userId="+userId+"  &&guid= "+guid+"  &&reagon= "+reagon);
     if (userId && guid && reagon) {
          //here I need to get userinformation with updated details of his/her account
     }};
```

Can someone suggest me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can I have any answers on this question?